# node project run on server properly but I get : "This site can’t be reached."

Tags: node.js, nginx, server

my nodejs app (app.js) listen to port 3000
this is app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");
const InputManager = require("./inputHandler/inputManagment");
const InputAnalyser = require("./inputHandler/inputAnalyser");
const CdfCreator=require("./inputHandler/outputCreator");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.post("/api/inputfile", (req, res) => {
  const informations = req.body;
  const age = informations.yearOfConstruction;
  const latitude = informations.latitude;
  const longitude = informations.longitude;
  const systemType = informations.systemType;
  const floor = informations.floor;
  const saveData = /*informations.saveData*/true;
  let inputManager = new InputManager({
    age: age,
    latitude: latitude,
    longitude: longitude,
    systemType: systemType,
    floor: floor,
  });
  inputManager.CreateInputBody();
  if (inputManager.error.length == 0) {
    const uuidInputFileName = uuidv4();
    fs.writeFile(
      "./RTX_InputFiles/RTX_LVL1_" + uuidInputFileName + ".txt",
      inputManager.inputFile,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log(
            "File created successfully. \nName: " +
              "RTX_LVL1_" +
              uuidInputFileName +
              ".txt\n" +
              "-".repeat(30) +
              "\n"
          );

          const inputAnalyser = new InputAnalyser(uuidInputFileName);
          inputAnalyser.RunAnalysis();
          var checker = setInterval(() => {
            if (inputAnalyser.status == 1) {
              const cdfCreator=new CdfCreator('RTX_InputFiles/'+inputManager.cdfCostRatio,'RTX_InputFiles/'+inputManager.outputFile);
              cdfCreator.createCdfandCov();
              // res.sendFile(inputManager.outputFile, {
              //   root: "./RTX_InputFiles/",
              // });
              res.send(cdfCreator.result);
              console.log(
                "Analysis done successfully.\n" + "-".repeat(30) + "\n"
              );
              if (!saveData) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  inputAnalyser.Clear({
                    DEL_input: "RTX_LVL1_" + uuidInputFileName + ".txt",
                    DEL_output: inputManager.outputFile,
                    DEL_cdf: inputManager.cdfCostRatio,
                  });
                }, 3000);
              }

              clearInterval(checker);
            } else if (inputAnalyser.error.length != 0) {
              res.send(
                "An error occured during computation! you can find more detail in terminal, code 4004!\n"
                //+JSON.stringify(inputAnalyser.error)
              );
              clearInterval(checker);
            }
          }, 5000);

          // setTimeout(() => {

          // }, 50000);

          //res.send("ok");
        }
      }
    );
  } else {
    res.json(inputManager.error);
  }
});
const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    "RTX is listening at PORT:\n" + PORT + "\n" + "-".repeat(30) + "\n"
  );
});
// async function getOutput(uuidInputFileName) {

//   return result;
// }
```

I use pm2 and status is:

```
┌─────┬────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name   │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ app    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 14908    │ 9m     │ 2    │ online    │ 0%       │ 262.2mb  │ civ… │ disabled │
└─────┴────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

nginx systemctl status is:

```
 civilrepo@civilRepo:/$ systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-02-23 18:08:48 +0330; 5s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 21258 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, s
  Process: 21265 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21262 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21271 (nginx)
    Tasks: 9
   Memory: 5.0M
      CPU: 63ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─21271 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on
           ├─21272 nginx: worker process
           ├─21273 nginx: worker process
           ├─21274 nginx: worker process
           ├─21275 nginx: worker process
           ├─21276 nginx: worker process
           ├─21277 nginx: worker process
           ├─21278 nginx: worker process
           └─21279 nginx: worker process

Feb 23 18:08:48 civilRepo systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 23 18:08:48 civilRepo systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
lines 1-24/24 (END)
```

and etc/nginx/sites-available/default is:

```
server {

listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

location / {
proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3000";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

}
```

this is pm2 logs:

```
 RTX is listening at PORT:
0|app      | 3000
0|app      | ------------------------------
```

the result of /$ sudo lsof -i:3000:

```
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node\x20/ 14908 civilrepo   20u  IPv6 1042798917      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

but when I try to send a request by POSTMAN I get this error:

```
POST http://81.31.168.76/api/inputfile
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 81.31.168.76:80
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 4e2c3fa5-6e43-4745-aa2c-e9a5d5e1a9a5
Host: 81.31.168.76
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
{
    "age" :1400,
  "latitude":35.68,
  "longitude" : 51.41,
  "systemType" :1,
  "floor" :12
}
```

it seems the app is running but the requests doesnt send to it. I appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Firefall is configured properly? Have you tried it via curl on the loopback address?

Comment: I dont Know how to config Firefall. I tried with curl and it works properly. 
 civilrepo@civilRepo:~$ curl 127.0.0.1:3000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>
</html>

Comment: If you cant even configure the firewall properly, please shut down the server.

Comment: oops! Sorry Mr. Zuckerberg.